# realm to Excel conversion

Tags: objective-c, io, realm

The realm-browser is great to look at realm-files, but what about exporting data from the realm-browser? Is there a tool out there to convert realm-files into other formats?

For example, is there an easy way to get data converted from .realm into an excel spreadsheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The realm-browser will eventually be extended to both import and export in various formats. The realm bindings will also get export to json capabilities.

Until then you can just iterate through allObjects and print them to a file with the built-in description method or extract each property and dump it in another preferred format.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas ! Can't wait until these extra features will be implemented :)